# Who is calling them "goniometric" instead of "trigonometric" functions?

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

In [Elementary Mathematics from a Higher Standpoint](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-662-49442-4.pdf#page=192) Klein advocated for calling the sine, cosine, etc functions [goniometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goniometer) functions instead of trigonometric functions because (paraphrasing) trigonometry is only one of the applications of these functions. This hasn't broadly caught on, but [there are *some* folks calling them goniometric functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Goniometric). Is this a regional thing? Is there some common modern textbook using this term? Who is calling them "goniometric functions" instead of "trigonometric functions"?

Comment: I actually read this long ago in a german math book. But it seems to be no common terminology.

Comment: In Italy they are called "goniometric functions", because they are related to "angles", and not necessarily to "*tri*angles". (But you can call them also "trigonometric functions", everyone will understand)

Answer (score 1):

It is a common terminology. It seems to me as a regional issue. lost in translation or something. I found out that goniometry (gonio as an angle) is often used in Slovakia, Czechia, Poland, Hungary, Germany... and I probably didn't hear the concept of trigonometry even in college. Correct me if I'm wrong. Whould like to change it. :-) As trigonometry exists for 4000 years probably more and it is about side ratio. Gonio(Angle) is a side product.
teach me...